# Out Function Problem

Tags: php

I wrote function that close the mysql session.

```
<?php
class mysql
{
    var $user;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $host;
    var $out;

    function mysql($username, $password, $database, $host)
    {
        $this->user = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host = $host;
    }
    function connect()
    {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database)
                or die("Error cannnot connect to mysql server");
        echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server";
    }
    function out()
    {
        mysql_close($this->out);
    }
}
$connect = new mysql('root','','test','127.0.0.1');
$connect->connect();
$connect->out();
?>
```

what the problem in the above code?

Comment: Please consider using PDO and prepared queries.  It will help prevent a few security issues with injection and what not.  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to close `$conn`.  Right now you are closing whatever is returned by the function... which isn't correct.  Since you are only making one connection and aren't keeping track of it anyway, just do this:

```
function out()
{
    mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: he actually never assigns to `$this->out` so he is trying to close an empty variable

Answer (score 1):

Add the variable that holds the db connection to the object instance variables:

```
<?php
class mysql
{
    var $user;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    var $host;
    var $out;
    var $conn;

    function mysql($username, $password, $database, $host)
    {
        $this->user = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->host = $host;
    }
    function connect()
    {
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database)
                or die("Error cannnot connect to mysql server");
        echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server";
    }
    function out()
    {
        mysql_close($this->conn);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the `$conn` variable in the class (e.g. as `$this->conn`) then call `mysql_close($this->conn)`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect doesn't take the database name as a parameter. You must use mysql_select_db() for that.

Also, use $this->out instead of $conn.

so the code would be:

```
 function connect()
    {
        $this->out = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password)
                or die("Error cannnot connect to mysql server");
        mysql_select_db($this->database) or die('Cannot select db');
        echo "Connected successfully to Mysql server";
    }
```